# Auto layout issues when building with Xcode 10.11 on Mac OS 10.10

Tags: objective-c, macos, autolayout

I am working on a slightly complex application where the main window is NSWindow subclass (currently subclass mostly uses superclass, except for keyStatus). The toolbar and its custom Items are laid out programmatically. There is one main view that has trailing alignment constraint that is used to resize the main view in response to a user action. Everything was working fine, till I updated to using Xcode 7 which is now building against 10.11 base sdk. Going back in sdks version is not an option wince a (non UI) framework we are using now can only be built against 10.11 sdk. 
Since the sdks update, on window resize the toolbar does not resize, the trailing constraint update does not update the underlying views. What changed between 10.10 and 10.11 for auto layout to stop working for me. Any pointers to what I should look for to fix this issue?

Forcing updates on views, subview, layout updates and updating all windows is not helping at all. The view only updates to new constraints when I moved the window between my two screens.

Comment: I think I have it mostly figured out, I need to explicitly issue layoutUpdate and updateSubtree to some of the subviews. Updating the container view wasn't doing it.